# Undefined behavior during function execution

Tags: c++, winapi, codeblocks

I am writing software in C++ using the Win32 API, however the following function running in a thread is presenting a strange issue that I have no idea about its source.

This function will be used to calibrate a light sensor and what it does is:

- It increases the light dimming from 0% to 100% in 5% steps;
- It compares the maximum & minimum range of the sensor (defined in    `main.h`);
- The minimum and maximum values read are stored in `get_lux_high` and    `get_lux_low`;
- Finally the values are updated at the software window.

During the execution of the software, the DIM is being displayed as (0, 48,49,50,51,50,51...).  During debugging the software, I noticed that the `count_dim` variable was being updated at the following line:

`wsprintfW (wbuf_readhigh, L"%d", get_lux_high);`

When I commented out the aforementioned command, the Software worked as it should be counting the DİM in 5% steps. I notice also if I change the declaration of `static int keep_low` to `int keep_low`, it also corrected the suppose "bug".

My question is, why or what is causing this issue in the software? I have never seen anything like this before. Until some days ago, the software was running perfectly. I just add other new functions in the software yesterday and then this problem came up. Note that no global variable is being applied at this function.

I am using CODE::Blocks v17.02 for compiling the software.

```
DWORD WINAPI ThreadCalibrate (LPVOID lpParam)   //THREAD USED FOR CALIBRATE THE SENSOR
{
    unsigned int get_lux_high = 0;
    unsigned int get_lux_low  = 0;
    unsigned int count_dim =0;

    wchar_t wbuf_readhigh [2];
    wchar_t wbuf_readlow  [2];
    wchar_t wbuf_getdim   [2];

    static int keep_low  = Max_SensorRange;    //Static Int variable to hold the lower value
    static int keep_high = Min_SensorRange;    //Static Int variable to hold the higher value

    SetWindowTextW(hcalibrate_status, L"%  CALIBRATING");
    for (count_dim; count_dim <= 100; count_dim +=5)
    {
        Register_Write(EQP_DIM_CONTROL,(int) count_dim, 0x00);
        Sleep(250);

        if (USB_Read(1) < keep_low)   //Compare if USB_Read is lower than keep_low
        {
            keep_low = USB_Read(1);   //Update keep_low
            get_lux_low = keep_low;
        }

        if (USB_Read(1) > keep_high)  //Compare if USB_Read is lower than keep_high
        {
            keep_high = USB_Read(1);  //Update keep_high
            get_lux_high = keep_high;
        }
        wsprintfW( wbuf_readhigh, L"%d", get_lux_high);
        SetWindowTextW(hMax_value, wbuf_readhigh);

        wsprintfW( wbuf_readlow, L"%d", get_lux_low);
        SetWindowTextW(hMin_value, wbuf_readlow);

        wsprintfW( wbuf_getdim, L"%ld", count_dim);
        SetWindowTextW( hCal, wbuf_getdim );
    }
    SetWindowTextW(hcalibrate_status, L"FINISHED" );    //Display Text
    SetWindowTextW( hCal, L" " );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `wchar_t wbuf_readhigh [2];` This only has room for one (wide) character plus the nul terminator. You overrun the buffer by printing 2-digit strings to it.

Comment: ot: `count_dim;` as init-statement of the loop looks odd, I would either remove it or delcare `count_dim` in the init-statement (and use an `int` instead of `unsigned` when you need an `int`)

Comment: what you call strange behavior has an official name, it is [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub)